# Cannot call method 'ui' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug, mocha.js, chai

using node with JADE as view engine. Im just trying to get into some page testing following a book called "Web Development with Node and Express."

Im getting following Error:

```
Cannot call method 'ui' of undefined
```

When i try to call mocha.ui

```
    58|                         script(type='text/javascript' src='/mocha/mocha.js')
    59|                         script(type='text/javascript' src='/chai/chai.js')
  > 60|                         -mocha.ui('tdd');
    61|                         -var assert = chai.assert;
    62|                         script(type='text/javascript' src='/qa/global-tests.js')
    63|                         -if(pageTestScript){
```

Whole call:

```
    //Page Tests + Global Tests
    -if(showTests){
        div(id="mocha")
        script(type='text/javascript' src='/mocha/mocha.js')
        script(type='text/javascript' src='/chai/chai.js')
        -mocha.ui('tdd');
        -var assert = chai.assert;
        script(type='text/javascript' src='/qa/global-tests.js')
        -if(pageTestScript){
            script(src= pageTestScript)
        -}
    -}
```

My Path structure is:

```
node_modules
->chai
->->chai.js
->mocha
->->mocha.js
```

Also the visibility for the node_modules are set:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/node_modules'));
```

Checking via firebug, following css is accessable:

```
link(rel='stylesheet', href='/mocha/mocha.css')
```

Tried moving js files to different folders, changed script calls, googled.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Pass mocha as a variable from the render statement in route file.

Comment: @AkashAgrawal: Thank you it works parseing a mocha instance. But shouldnt is also be possible to init it by the script call?

Comment: Nopes. You are confusing front end script calls. I'll write a complete answer.

Comment: @MortalFool If your "ADDED AFTER SOLUTION (handles mocha tests in client)" section is meant to show your code *after* you solved your problem, then this belongs in an answer, not in the question itself. (This is standard Stack Overflow editorial practice.) So please either move it to an answer, or if I'm mistaken about the meaning of that section, then please explain what this section is doing there. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you want `mocha` to be available to jade as a variable by using a script tag. You seem confused between variables in front-end and back-end. The mocha variable you are using is a backend variable supplied by node. It has absolutely no relation with the mocha.js in your script tag.

For lines beginning with `-` or `=`, jade evaluates these and replaces them with their values server-side. Script tags get evaluated in browser. All it does is convert something like

```
script(src="hello.js)
```

to

```
<script src="hello.js">
```

Jade DOES NOT run the scripts mentioned in script tags.

**ADDED AFTER SOLUTION (handles mocha tests in client):**

```
-if(showTests){
    div(id="mocha")
    script(type='text/javascript' src='/mocha/mocha.js')
    script(type='text/javascript' src='/chai/chai.js')
    script(type='text/javascript').
        mocha.ui('tdd');
        var assert = chai.assert;
    script(type='text/javascript' src='/qa/global-tests.js')
    script(type='text/javascript').
        console.log('Test console output');
    -if(pageTestScript){
        script(src= pageTestScript)
    -}
    script(type='text/javascript').
        mocha.run();
-}
```